# Regex delete duplicate urls

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have a list with several urls like

```
google.com
google.com/1
google.com/2
google.com/3
google.com/4
google.com/5
google.com/6
yahoo.com
yahoo.com/1
yahoo.com/2
yahoo.com/3
yahoo.com/4
yahoo.com/5
yahoo.com/6
```

How can I remove the first the 3 entries keeping `google.com/3` to `6` and same goes for yahoo?

Comment: Under what form do you have those entries? A collection, a string, something else? Also why is your question titled with duplicate urls where I cannot see any duplicate urls in your list.

Comment: @Tim your edit implies in a different a different answer

Comment: @Jader Dias: I have just reformatted it as the linebreaks in the original post were not visible because james hadn't used the `{}` button for the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"^        # Start at the start of a line
    [^/\r\n]+  # Match one or more characters except /
    $          # Match the end of the line, thereby ensuring that
               # the entire line does not contain a /
    (?:        # Match the following group:
     \r\n      # - a linebreak
     .*        # - an entire line
    ){2}       # exactly twice
    \r\n       # Match the final line break", 
    "", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Resulting string:

```
google.com/3
google.com/4
google.com/5
google.com/6
yahoo.com/3
yahoo.com/4
yahoo.com/5
yahoo.com/6
```

Comment: you answered the the question title and I answered the last question in the question body

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Regex are the best approach to this. But here's it anyway:

```
s/(google.com[\s/\d]*){3}//
s/(yahoo.com[\s/\d]*){3}//
```

Regexes are enclosed in slashes and the preceeding `s` is substitution in `vi` notation

Comment: since I answered this the OP edited the question. please check the original version before you criticize this answer